# When would IPSec sequence numbers be ignored?

Tags: ipsec

Under what circumstances and why are IPSec sequences ignored by the recipient?

The only reason I can think of anyone wishing to ignore sequence numbers and therefore not use anti-replay protection would be in the case of ESP only providing confidentiality since as the sequence number in the ESP header would not by protected by an integrity check, the receiver can have no assurance that the message has not been modified. Are there any other reasons?

Comment: ignored on purpose? or by mistake?